# Цикл, повторение

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Я хочу, чтобы каждый раз выдавалась другая цифра и другой цвет, а не одинаково, можете помочь и написать как правильно?

```
a = random.choice(['red', 'black'])
c = random.randint(1,13)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/rl':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'пиши число от 1 до 12, либо цвет');
    if message.text ==  c :
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "поздравляю! вы отгадали правильное число!");
    if message.text == a :
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'поздравляю! вы отгадали число'); 
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите так как надо!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы создаете переменные `a` и `c` один раз - одно значение постоянно.
А для желаемого результата вам нужно создавать их при каждом вызове функции:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    a = random.choice(['red', 'black'])
    c = random.randint(1,13)

    if message.text == '/rl':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'пиши число от 1 до 12, либо цвет');
    if message.text ==  c :
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "поздравляю! вы отгадали правильное число!");
    if message.text == a :
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'поздравляю! вы отгадали число'); 
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'введите так как надо!')
```

Comment: спасибо! исправил

Comment: Хмм. Так при каждом новом сообщении будет новое число. Т.е. я введу сначала, скажем, "1" - ответ будет "ну угадал". Потом сразу же повторю "1" - а теперь угадал. (Или второй, более вероятный, вариант, переберу все числа от 1 до 12 и все равно не угадаю). Думаю, нужно сгенерировать раз и пока пользователь не угадал помнить. И заново генерировать после угадывания или по специальной команде.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, дополните мой ответ, если вам не сложно :)